# Trampoline, recursion and lazy evaluation

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, trampolines

I'm trying to implement basic lazy sequences in JavaScript. I'm only using closures and continuations. This is what I got so far:

```
var cons = curry(function(x, y, list){
  return list(x, y);
});
var head = function(seq){
  return seq(function(x, y){
    return x;
  });
};
var tail = function(seq){
  return seq(function(x, y){
    return y();
  });
};
var iterate = function(f){
  var next = f();
  if (next != null) {
    return cons(next, function(){
      return iterate(f);
    });
  }
};
var take = curry(function(n, seq){
  if (n && seq != null) {
    return cons(head(seq), function(){
      return take(n - 1, tail(seq));
    });
  }
});
var doSeq = curry(function(n, f, seq){
  while (n-- && seq != null) {
    f(head(seq));
    seq = tail(seq);
  }
});

var rand = iterate(Math.random);
var log = function(x){ console.log(x) };

doSeq(10, log, rand); //=> logs 10 random numbers
```

I didn't post the [curry](https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/a20352adc35072a1606b) function as it isn't directly related to the question.

Now the deal breaker is `filter`. The canonical implementation is tail recursive:

```
var filter = curry(function(f, seq){
  if (seq == null) {
    return;
  }
  if (!f(head(seq))) {
    return filter(f, tail(seq)); // recursion
  }
  return cons(head(seq), function(){
    return filter(f, tail(seq));
  });
});
```

When I run it many times on a sequence the stack will eventually blow up:

[image: Imgur]

I know a common workaround  is to use a [trampoline](http://raganwald.com/2013/03/28/trampolines-in-javascript.html), and that's relatively easy in an eager world, but it seems daunting to implement it for a lazy sequence. I found an intricate [solution in Scheme](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-45/srfi-45.html), but I gave up on trying to implement it as-is in JavaScript.

Is this as complicated as it seems? Is there another way to solve this issue, with iteration maybe? Any hints on porting the Scheme code to JavaScript in a sane way?

Comment: Btw, your `iterate` function is not very functional, as it does not save any state. Use `function iterate(f, cur){ if (cur != null) { var next = f(cur); return cons(cur, function(){ return iterate(f, next); }); } }` so that `var ints = iterate(function(x){return x+1}, 0)`

Comment: Yeah, will try that, I'm simply using an IIFE closure to keep track of the value for now as you see in the JSBin demo.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work. `head(tail(ints)) != head(tail(ints))` - wait, what?! Every `tail` call increases the result by one.

Comment: I'm not following... It works fine, I'm not sure what you mean, I tried ints, fibos... http://jsbin.com/taqij/1/edit

Comment: Try http://jsbin.com/kugajala/2/edit - I would've expected to get `1` always when alerting the first `int`

Comment: Oh I see, that looks indeed like an issue.

Comment: Not knowing enough JS, but the problem seems to be that cons() does not work tail-lazy. What this means is that cons must never evaluate its 2nd argument (the tail of the list that gets constructed). This should be solely the job of tail()

Comment: @Bergi: I ended up just doing this http://jsbin.com/kugajala/6/edit.

Comment: @elclanrs: no no no! What about `var some = take(10, fibo()); tail(some)(alert); tail(some)(alert)`? You're effectively destroying any sharing. Believe me, this will bite you in more complex examples.

Comment: @Bergi: Aight, point taken, I would've discovered this myself and wasted a bunch of time, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it <s>while still being lazy</s><sup>1</sup>:

```
var filter = curry(function(f, seq){
  while (seq != null && !f(head(seq)))
      seq = tail(seq);
  if (seq == null)
    return;
  return cons(head(seq), function() {
    return filter(f, tail(seq))
  });
});
```

Maybe easier readable:

```
var filter = curry(function(f, seq){
  for (; seq != null; seq = tail(seq))
    if ( f(head(seq)) )
      return cons(head(seq), function() {
        return filter(f, tail(seq))
      });
});
```

<sub>1): Your representation of lazy sequences does not seem to have a way to express a maybe-empty (yet undetermined) list</sub>

Comment: If this is still as lazy as the recursive version, is the Scheme solution overkill or even necessary? Btw, I already experimented with `constant`, but it has a problem, it will blow up the stack depending on the order of composition, see http://jsbin.com/jevom/1/edit and http://jsbin.com/qamiq/1/edit

Comment: Ouch, of course that `constant` function is *not* lazy evaluated - I'm too much in Haskell :-/

Comment: Ok, so I think I'm going with this. I was too concerned with trampolining a recursive function that I missed the obvious... Thanks.

Comment: Actually I think `seq = tail(seq)` in a loop *is* trampolining :-)

Comment: Yes, in general I suppose it is, but the Scheme solution seems to suggest a way to trampoline a promise that will execute the thunk later, even more lazily, if I understand correctly.